# Turning code (instead of data) into a vector

Tags: r, string, gsub

I have the following code:

```
install.packages("microbenchmark")
install.packages("readxl")
install.packages("data.table")
```

I would like to create a vector of a variable amount of package names without having to actually write the vector (these package names are or not necessarily installed). Desired output:

```
vector <- c("microbenchmark","readxl", "data.table")
```

I thought I would feed the packages to `vector` as a string and go from there:

```
input <- 'install.packages("microbenchmark")
install.packages("readxl")
install.packages("data.table")'

vector <- gsub("install.packages\(", " ", input)
```

But it does not even create the vector properly. How should I do this?

Comment: not exactly clear on your question, can you look at my edits and see if that is correct? or rollback if not

Comment: @rawr Thank, yeah that makes sense. I was not even aware that there was an actual difference between double and single quotation marks.

Comment: like this? `stringr::str_extract_all(input, '(?<=").*(?=")')[[1]]` well you could escape doubles between doubles, eg, `"nested \"quotes\" string"` or use only doubles inside wrapped in single (or vice versa), the problem was the parser doesnt know where your string starts and ends if you only use one

Comment: @rawr Thanks, that was a very import lesson!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like the following answers the question.

```r
input <- 'install.packages("microbenchmark")
install.packages("readxl")
install.packages("data.table")'

input <- scan(text = input, what = character())
sub('^.*\\"(.*)\\".*$', '\\1', input)
#> [1] "microbenchmark" "readxl"         "data.table"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

```
scan(text=gsub('install.packages|["()]', '', input), what='')
Read 3 items
[1] "microbenchmark" "readxl"         "data.table"
```

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness, here is an approach which uses `str_match_all()` from the `stringr` package to extract all characters which are enclosed in double quotes `"`:

```
library(magrittr) # piping used for readability
vector <- stringr::str_match_all(input, '"(.*)"') %>% 
    extract2(1) %>% 
    .[, 2]

vector
```

> ```
> [1] "microbenchmark" "readxl"         "data.table"
> ```

`str_match_all()` returns a list of character matrices. Therefore, the subsequent steps are required to extract the vector.

#### Data

```
input <- 'install.packages("microbenchmark")
install.packages("readxl")
install.packages("data.table")'

input
```

> ```
> [1] "install.packages(\"microbenchmark\")\ninstall.packages(\"readxl\")\ninstall.packages(\"data.table\")"
> ```